# How to connect an Oracle database from PHP

Tags: php, oracle

How do I connect to an Oracle database from PHP?

Comment: What are you looking for, connection string? Take a look at PDO or OCI_ at http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.oci8.php

Comment: One important thing: If you want to connect to a remote Oracle server then you need to install the Oracle Instant Client. More information and a link to OIC here: http://de.php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Forth link in google after searching for your exact questions brought up the following link: http://me2learn.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/connect-php-with-oracle-database/

```
<?php
    $db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.34)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)))" ;

    if($c = OCILogon("system", "your database password", $db))
    {
        echo "Successfully connected to Oracle.\n";
        OCILogoff($c);
    }
    else
    {
        $err = OCIError();
        echo "Connection failed." . $err[text];
    }
?>
```

Comment: That blogpost appears to be windows specific.

Answer (score 4):

I assumed you want to connect php with oracle databases. so, I give you two of file, this is represent a basic php-oracle for your reference. good luck!

form.php

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
  <label> User Name
  <input type="text" name="nis" id="nis">
  </label>
  <label> Password
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Login">
  </label>
</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php

//create table users (userid varchar2(10), password varchar2(20), constraint pk_users primary key (userid));
//insert into users values('kharis', 'pass123');

$nis = isset($_POST['nis']) == true ? $_POST['nis'] : '';
$password= isset($_POST['password']) == true ? $_POST['password'] : '';

if(empty($nis) or empty($password)){
    echo "UserID atau Password kosong";}
else
{
    $db = "(DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = patronus.ad-ins.com)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
        )
      )" ;
    $connect = oci_connect("HR", "hr", "XE");
    $query = "SELECT * from users WHERE userid='".$nis."' and password='".$password."'";
    $result = oci_parse($connect, $query);
    oci_execute($result);
    $tmpcount = oci_fetch($result);
    if ($tmpcount==1) {
        echo "Login Success";}
    else
    {
        echo "Login Failed";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP provides [Oracle OCI8 functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php). Other options are PDO with the [Oracle Driver](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php) and (if oracle supports it) [ODBC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php).

Answer (score 1):

> I have created a connection in easiest way   as follows:
>
> Step 1. Determine what PHP bit version (32-bit or 64-bit) you are running. 
>   If PHP_INT_SIZE is value of 4, then version is 32-bit. If PHP_INT_SIZE is value of 8, then version is 64-bit. Use the following code below:

```
<?php
    switch(PHP_INT_SIZE) {
        case 4:
            echo '32-bit version of PHP';
            break;
        case 8:
            echo '64-bit version of PHP';
            break;
        default:
            echo 'PHP_INT_SIZE is ' . PHP_INT_SIZE;
    } 
?>
```

> Step 2. Download the "InstantClient Package - Basic" for Windows from
>   the [OTN InstantClient page][1]. Make sure you download the corresponding bit-version from step 1.
>
> Step 3. Unzip the InstantClient files to `C:\instantclient_11_2` and
>   edit the Windows PATH environment to include `C:\instantclient_11_2`.
>   For example, on Windows XP, follow `Start > Control Panel > System >

```
Advanced > Environment Variables` and edit `PATH` in the `System`
> variables list.
```

> ```
> Step 3. In your `php.ini` file, enable the following lines:
> ```

```
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll

Finally, restart your Apache server.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear from your question if you want to configure your PHP install to connect to oracle or if you just want the php syntax to make the connection?

As there is already a Windows specific answer and the connection systax here, these links should point you in the right direction for a linux based install of the Oracle client libraries.

The basic steps are..

- uncompress the Oracle Client Libraries (Basic, SDK and sqlplus packages)
- add LD_LIBRARY_PATH to your environment
- fix some symlinks for the libraries
- install PECL OCI8, this compiles the shared object so your system will need a C compiler
- enable the extension in the php.ini file. Remember your system might have separate php.ini files for CLI and webserver so check for both.
- restart your webserver

These steps are on multiple blog posts so I won't reinvent the wheel here. but here are some links that look pretty good

- http://antistatique.net/fr/nous/bloggons/2013/03/25/install-php-oracle-oci-extension-11-2-on-mac-os-x-10-8
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html

Answer (score 0):

PHP has several extensions that let applications use Oracle Database. The PHP extensions that connect to Oracle Database are written in C and linked into the PHP
binary. The extensions are:

1. OCI8
2. PDO_OCI driver for PDO

You can also use the ODBC extension;

***Using PHP OCI8 Extension:-***

```
<?php
// Create connection to Oracle
$conn = oci_connect("phphol", "welcome", "//localhost/orcl");
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
}

// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

The `oci_connect()` function contains the `username` as `phphol`, the `password` as `welcome`, and the `connection string` as `//localhost/orcl`. In this case, Oracle's Easy Connect connection string syntax is used. It consists of the hostname and the DB service name.

The `oci_close()` function closes the connection. Any standard connections not explicitly closed will be automatically released when the script ends.

***Using PHP PDO Extension:-***

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost/XE', 'hr', 'welcome');
$s = $dbh->prepare("select city from locations");
$s->execute();
while (($r = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) != false) {
 echo htmlentities($r['CITY']) . "<br>";
}
?>
```

More details can be found below references:-

1. [oci_connect — Connect to an Oracle database](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php)
2. [OCI8 - Examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.examples.php)
3. [PDO_OCI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php)
4. [PDO_OCI DSN — Connecting to Oracle databases](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php)
5. [Using PHP OCI8 with Oracle Database 11g](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm)
6. [Web 2.0 Applications with PHP and Oracle Database 11g](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/opensrclang/php/php.htm)