# Error when connecting WordPress to Oracle

Tags: php, wordpress, oracle, connection, database-connection

I'm trying to connect Oracle database to Wordpress site and select some table. But I have no luck, I got this error `PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()`

I already commented out the extension=php_oci8.dll and extension=php_oci8_11g.dll in php.ini and still getting the same error.

How to fix this?

```
$tns = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.PH)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = XXXXXXX.XXXXXX.XX)))";
$dbaseconnection = oci_connect("username","password", $tns);
```

Comment: Did you install oracle client?

Comment: Have you restarted the server after enabling the extension?

Comment: @BugCoder yes, but still not working

Comment: @User014019 check following links https://me2learn.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/connect-php-with-oracle-database/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947809/how-to-connect-php-and-oracle-data-database

Comment: @BugCoder i just talked to web hosting tech support where my wordpress installed. he/she said that it is not possible to run the oci in shared hosting