# Connect to an Oracle database which is situated on a different server using PHP

Tags: php, linux, oracle

I want to create a PHP project with existing Oracle database.I have only installed the Apache and PHP on the server with Linux OS.
I didn't work with Oracle previously. I need to connect to an Oracle database which is situated on a different server.

Is anyone explain me to how to connect the Oracle db which is on another server?

Which package or driver  need to used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947809/how-to-connect-php-and-oracle-data-database

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ODBC, then you need to use the PHP's ODBC driver rather than the OCI8 driver. Otherwise, you need the Oracle client installed on your webserver (even if it's just Oracle's Instant Client) and then you can use OCI8.

Comment: But the ODBC driver itself requires an Oracle Client. So, no matter which one you need, you have to install an Oracle Client in any case.