# Connect oracle database in php using xampp

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle11g

How to connect Oracle database in php using xampp?

Is it right?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username= "username";
$password= "password";
$dbname = "db";

$conn= new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

// check connection
if($conn->connect_error){
   die("connection Failed:".$conn->connection_error);
}
```

Comment: That's for MySQL/Maria DB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect an Oracle database from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947809/how-to-connect-an-oracle-database-from-php)

Comment: PDO is a generalized and consistent interface for accessing databases in PHP. It can also be used for Oracle databases, but the specific driver might not yet present. Test this with [print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php). See [How to install](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try This

Review the code in $HOME/public_html/connect.php

```
<?php
// Create connection to Oracle
$conn = oci_connect("phphol", "welcome", "//localhost/orcl");
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
}
// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

The oci_connect() function contains the username, the password and the connection string. In this case, Oracle's Easy Connect connection string syntax is used. It consists of the hostname and the DB service name.

The oci_close() function closes the connection. Any standard connections not explicitly closed will be automatically released when the script ends.

Comment: It is possible that this extension is not present.

Answer (score 1):

```
$username="OE";
$password="OE";
$db="(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
)";

$connection = oci_connect($username, $password, $db);

if (!$connection) {
$e = oci_error();
echo htmlentities($e["message"]);
}
```

Comment: It is possible that this extension is not present.

Comment: Please check that's extension in php.ini (Apache webserver) : extension=php_oci8_12c.dll;

Comment: Service name should be xe?

Comment: Now I am facing the login issue in sql developer
network adapter couldn't establish the connection.


hostname : localhost

port 1521.

Answer (score -2):

Try this just make an query request with this function

> mysqli_query($connectionhandler, $sqlquery);

Comment: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure first you can be helpful, before answering a question.

Comment: Ok now it will be work because i use this too in php 7.3

Comment: This is not explaining how to connect to a database. And yes, it will work with a MySQL database, but not with Oracle database. I like your enthusiasm, but this answer is not useful.